# Is it possible to specify log level with a string, not an int?

Tags: python-logging

I know I can specify a log level like this:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.log(level=50, msg='critical log')
CRITICAL:root:critical log
```

Is there a built in way for me to accomplish the same thing with the string 'CRITICAL', instead of the number 50? Something like

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.log(level_string='CRITICAL', msg='critical log')
CRITICAL:root:critical log
```

Comment: Well, you could declare a variable `CRITICAL` with value 50. It will be exactly the same except for the quotes, which I don't believe are important for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the predefined logging methods or use the built-in conversion function:

```py
import logging

# this works:
logging.critical("critical log")

# the logging module also provides predefined constants:
logging.log(level=logging.CRITICAL, msg="critical log")

# you can also use `getattr` if you have the level as string:
logging.log(getattr(logging, "CRITICAL"), "critical log")

# or if you really, really want to use the string (not recommended):
logging.log(level=logging._checkLevel("CRITICAL"), msg="critical log")
```

Comment: The second solution is accessing a protected member - this should not be the preferred solution

Comment: @felice added how it could work without the protected member, and added a note that doing that is not recommended. but don't know what the question really wants to achieve, and `_checkLevel()` is the builtin way to convert the level string to the level int

Answer (score 0):

[`getLevelName`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLevelName) works for me:

```
>>> logging.getLevelName("CRITICAL")
50
```

which results in

```
>>> logging.log(level=logging.getLevelName("CRITICAL"), msg='critical log')
```